# gcloud init command cannot run with disabled prompts

Tags: google-cloud-sdk

I'm currently struggling with the installation of Google Cloud SDK on Windows 11 (GoogleCloudSDKInstaller.exe). First I installed it in the C:/ directory, then I had to uninstall it because something with python didn't work. Then I tried installing it in my user directory, but I can't run the gcloud init command. I always get this message:

```
Welcome! This command will take you through the configuration of gcloud.

ERROR: (gcloud.init) Invalid value for [disable_prompts/--quiet]: gcloud init command cannot run with disabled prompts.
```

I got the same error already when the command was run by the installer. I tried the --quiet=false parameter, but then I get this message:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.init) argument --quiet/-q: ignored explicit argument 'false'
```

Tried uninstalling it, removing path variables, reinstalling, tried powershell but it doesn't work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$ gcloud config set disable_prompts false` with the error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.init) Invalid value for [disable_prompts/--quiet]: gcloud init command cannot run with disabled prompts.

Do note that if you uninstalled the gcloud CLI, you must reboot your system before you install the gcloud CLI again and Cloud SDK requires supported Python versions 3 (3.5 to 3.9)

You can refer to this document to guide you on [installing Google Cloud SDK on Windows.](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install-sdk#installing_the_latest_version)